# Insert form buttons outside a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, hyperlink

Is there a Rails library that allows you to insert form buttons and use them as hyperlinks instead? I think I've seen it somewhere before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `button_to`, but in general it's not a *great* idea.

The `button_to` helper is implemented as a form POST by default, which means it's a bad choice for actions that aren't idempotent (i.e. regular GET actions). Stick to links as much as possible.

Comment: Agreed.

If it must look button-like, then use CSS.

Comment: Cool. Is there a way to style it and make these buttons/fonts bigger?

Comment: And when I use consecutive button_to's, they go on separate lines. Is there a way to keep them side by side?